# Placeholder Text in search box - Cartodb

Tags: javascript, carto, html

I am trying to add `placeholder` text to the Cartodb searchbox using the following DOM code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].placeholder='Search Your Constituency';
```

It actually does not seem to work.

Comment: What happens when you try? Nothing? Could you elaborate a bit on what you have tried to do in order to solve it?

Comment: It is working but when I create a visual and embed the iframe, it is not working. 

and also I am not able to view the map. here is what I am seeing. http://goo.gl/Psq2lu

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you added  code within the infowindow template, unfortunately it breaks the visualization. If you remove it the map will work.

Also, If you want to add or customize something in the map (javascript, styles, etc), I encourage you to try CartoDB.js library (https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js). Create your map using a viz.json url and then change whatever you need :).

Hope it helps you!